# Calculate a list of cubes in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

So I'm doing some Prolog in SWI-Prolog and I've come across a little snag. I must create a list of cubes, given an input list. The code I currently have is

```
cubes([Head|Tail],Cubes) :-
    cubes([Head|Tail],Cubes,[]).
cubes([Head|Tail],Cubes,ActualCubes) :-
    X is Head^3,
    append(ActualCubes,[X],NewCubes),
    cubes(Tail,Cubes,NewCubes).
cubes([Tail],Cubes,ActualCubes) :-
    X is Tail^3,
    append(ActualCubes,[X],NewCubes),
    Cubes is NewCubes.
```

When I run that it gives an error, specifically...

```
ERROR: '.'/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[8]' ("x" must hold one character)
   Exception: (7) cbList([1, 2], _G296, []) ? creep
```

I'm not entirely sure why this error is occurring but it seems to happen around the very last line, Cubes is NewCubes. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're making different `cubes` predicates with differing numbers of arguments. This is bound to cause both conceptual and syntactical problems, so at that point, re-think what you're doing. In this case, try to expand the ways you can use pattern matching and recursion:

```
cubes([],[]).
cubes([H|T], [Y|Z]):-
        Y is H*H*H,
        cubes(T,Z).


betterCubes([],[]).
betterCubes([H|T], [Y|Z]):-
        ( 
          var(Y) , nonvar(H)    -> Y is H*H*H
        ; nonvar(Y) , var(H)    -> H is Y**(1.0/3.0) 
        ; nonvar(Y) , nonvar(H) -> H*H*H =:= Y
        ),
        betterCubes(T,Z).
```

Comment: Next exercise, try to do it in an even briefer way. Can you eliminate the use of `is` here?

Comment: I should clarify, the input is something like cubes([1,2,3],X) and the output should be X = 1, 8, 27 and if they input X (i.e. cubes([1,2,3],[1,8,27])) it should return false.

Comment: Well, I intended to leave it vague to give you something to work through. But I added more to my answer that does what you want. As a bonus, this one also computes cube roots if you leave the second argument variable, but I've left a slight bug with that (the interpreter will require an extra `.` when you use it this way), so if you're interested it's a good exercise to figure out how to make that go away, giving yourself a cube function that automatically does cube roots too.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to exercise a pattern known as *accumulator*, rewriting a binary relation with an *added argument* that holds intermediary results.

Syntax errors apart, you should note that an accumulator it's useless here, because each element of a list is in relation *only* with the corresponding element of the other list.

library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)) has [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3)/3 for such common case:

```
cube(N, C) :-
    C is N^3.
cubes(Ns, Cs) :-
    maplist(cube, Ns, Cs).
```

and library([clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29)) has interesting features that allow (in integer domain) a better *relational* handling of arithmetic. Replace cube above with

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

cube(N, C) :-
    N ^ 3 #= C.
```

and you are allowed to write

```
?- cubes(X,[1,8,27]).
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

Comment: In my interpreter (swi-prolog), your cube function gives a not-instantiated error when `N` is left as a variable. Is this an interpreter difference? It's also not clear why this would satisfy the OP's [secondary constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927028/calculate-a-list-of-cubes-in-prolog/11927317#comment15884987_11927317) I also have the gripe that using `maplist` is a bit like cheating for an exercise like this which is obviously meant to get the programmer to think about pattern matching and concise recursion. Sweeping it into `maplist` is artificially concise, for a learner.

Comment: @EMS: you are right, and already explained well OP's  problem. About the problem with library(clpfd), AFAIK such code should work. Of course using (#=)/2, while is/2 gives the error...

Comment: @EMS: an exercise can have many solutions, I think the best solution here would be to spot that the global pattern to apply here is a maplist and then recode the maplist if it's interesting for you. This way you both learn the recursion and learn the functionnal idioms at once.

Comment: maplist and other higher order idioms (folds, filters, etc) are commonly coded as a starting point for learners in all declarative languages that use it (haskell, OCaml, Prolog, etc). Once this coding is done I find it counter productive to continue using basic recursion instead: it's harder to read (doesn't highlight the concept) and longer to type. Longer to type means more chances to make errors, too.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, one can also accomplish the desired goal with a *difference list*:

```
cubes( [] , [] ) .
cubes( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :-
  Y is X*X*X ,
  cubes( Xs , Ys )
  .
```

The output list is built as we traverse the source list, recursing down. The final goal `cubes([],[])` unifies the empty list `[]` with the tail of the output list, making it a correct list.

The other approach is to use an accumulator, which builds the output in reverse order, then reverses it:

```
cubes(Xs,Ys) :-
  cubes(Xs,[],T) ,
  reverse(T,Ys)
  .

cubes( [] , Ys, Ys ).
cubes( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :-
  T is X*X*X ,
  cubes( Xs , [T|Ts] , Ys )
  .
```

Both are (our should be) properly tail recursive.